# What does "lay to heart" mean?

Tags: word-usage, word-formation

I am studying a few words in [Noah Webster's 1828 dictionary](http://www.webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/Regard) that have connected definitions or meanings:  *hearken, heed, observe, attend*, and *regard*.

One definition of 'regard' is:
"To consider seriously; to lay to heart"

What does the phrase "lay to heart" mean and where did it originally get its meaning?

Comment: "Take to heart" means much the same thing. Shakespeare used the phrase I'm sure. Not an answer. I just wonder if it was adapted from that.

Comment: ***Lay to heart***: to set one's mind strongly upon: to be deeply moved by something http://www.finedictionary.com/Lay%20to%20heart.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very closely related to 'take to heart' and has largely been replaced by it.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lay%20to%20heart%2Ctake%20to%20heart&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clay%20to%20heart%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20to%20heart%3B%2Cc0) *take to heart vs lay to heart*

It means 'to internalise'.

Verb 1. internalise - incorporate within oneself; make subjective or personal; "internalize a belief" 
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/internalise

Comment: *Lay to heart:* http://www.wordreference.com/thesaurus/lay%20to%20heart